# Constructors can't have type parameters.dart(type_parameter_on_constructor)

Tags: dart, factory

I am using the following dart packages (json_annotation, json_serializable, build_runner) to serialize/de-serialize json according to this [page](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).

This is my code:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'car_type.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class CarType {

  final int id;

  @JsonKey(name: 'type_label')
  final String label;

  final String description;

  CarType(this.id, this.label, this.description);

  factory CarType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CarTypeFromJson(json);

  factory List<CarType> CarType.fromJsonList(dynamic jsonArray){
    final list = jsonArray as List;
    final carTypesList =  list.map((i) => CarType.fromJson(i));
    return carTypesList;
  }
}
```

So with the `factory List<CarType> CarType.fromJsonList(dynamic jsonArray)` I want to pass a json array to get back a list of CarType objects. However I'am getting a couple of compiler errors namely:

- This function has a return type of 'List', but doesn't end with a return statement.dart(missing_return)
- The default constructor is already defined.dart(duplicate_constructor_default)
- Constructors can't have type parameters.dart(type_parameter_on_constructor)

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
factory List<CarType> CarType.fromJsonList(dynamic jsonArray){
```

You can't specify a return type for a constructor.
The return type is always the same as the class the constructor is member of.

Just replace `factory` with `static` and you should be fine,
except `json_serializable` expects a factory constructor, then you need to remove the return type and find another approach to get the `List`.

Comment: But why is `CarType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CarTypeFromJson(json);` returning an object just fine? Does it mean I can return an object of type dynamic as long as i don't specify a type?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I can't see the return type of `_$CarTypeFromJson(json);` from here ;-) and I doubt it returns an Object. I assume it returns `_$CarType extends CarType {...}`

Comment: I see, it returns the following: 
`CarType _$CarTypeFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return CarType(json['id'] as int, json['type_label'] as String,
      json['description'] as String);
}` So I assume constructs essentially only return objects of their class only?

Comment: "only return objects of their class only?" That's the sole purpose of constructors. While normal constructors always return a new instance of exactly their own class, factory constructors are more flexible and allow to return subclasses and existing instances.